# In Python, given a class A, why do subsequent calls to id(A()) return the same value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, built-in

I am using the python 2.7 interpreter, and have found the following behavior interesting enough to ask about.

Given an empty class:

```
class A():
    pass
```

I can create separate instances, and like expected they have separate ids:

```
a = A()
b = A()
id(a)
>>> XXXXXXXX44
id(b)
>>> XXXXXXXX16
```

But when I make subsequent calls to the id builtin, without a variable to hold the instance being created, I see the same id being returned.

```
id(A())
>>> XXXXXXXX88
id(A())
>>> XXXXXXXX88
```

Even stranger, when I mix another instantiation held by a variable in between calls to `id(A())` the behavior changes:

```
id(A())
>>> XXXXXXXX88
a = A()
>>> XXXXXXXX88
id(A())
>>> XXXXXXXX44
```

Any intuitions on this behavior?

Comment: Immediately after writing this I've begun to suspect instances are being garbage collected immediately when not bound, and ids are reused. Still, I'd appreciate a thorough explanation if someone knows.

Comment: yes, dupe allright! good find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id(A())` creates an `A` instance, which is garbage collected right after the exit of the `id` method.

So a new call to `id(A())` reuses the reference.

If you store the first reference in a variable, Python cannot reuse the reference since it's used.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: you had figured out the answer yourself BTW.

Comment: I wasn't sure though, it's better to know